# Joining two tables on a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Every day I will download a "product inventory" list from an third party source, the list is in the format like this:

| Product Code | Product Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 100 |
| 2 | Pear | 200 |
| 3 | Banana | 150 |
| 4 | Grape | 400 |

However, not all product shows up everyday.  In the next day the report may look like this:

| Product Code | Product Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 120 |
| 3 | Banana | 200 |
| 4 | Grape | 320 |
| 5 | Kiwi | 80 |

And I want to be able to join these two tables and build an "product movement" report like the following

| Product Code | Product Name | Delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | +20 |
| 2 | Pear | -200 |
| 3 | Banana | +50 |
| 4 | Grape | -80 |
| 5 | Kiwi | +80 |

Could someone please give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the first table in `Sheet1` starting at cell `A1`, and the second table in `Sheet2` starting at cell `A1`.

Then use this formula in `Sheet3`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      if( 
        isnumber(Sheet1!A1:C) * (column(Sheet1!A1:C) = column(C1)), 
        - Sheet1!A1:C, 
        Sheet1!A1:C 
      ); 
      Sheet2!A1:C 
    }, 
    "select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3) 
     where Col1 is not null 
     group by Col1, Col2", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

Format the third column like this:

**Format > Number > More formats > Custom number format >** `+#,##0;-#,##0;±0`.